# How to share data between two models in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am implementing a web app on RoR. My first model has got three fields as input (weight, height and gender) while my second model has got 2 fields (weight and height). I have implemented the first model and am thinking to create a separate model for the one with two fields. The task is that when I  put data into second model (which i am thinking to implement), my code should extract all the data from the first model i.e the one with three fields, and then I should perform calculations on it.

My question is:

Will the same db be shared between these two models? and how should i extract the data from the first model when I enter and submit the data into second model form?

Comment: What's the logical relationship between the two models?  Do they have a relationship, or are they both effectively subclasses of some generic parent class?  If the latter, then the STI suggestion below is good.

Comment: They don't have any relation. I have not made the second model yet, the one with two fields, but plan to do so. My project involves using data from the main model with three fields and show the result output in small model (2 fields) view.

Answer (score 0):

From the details of your question it's not entirely certain, but perhaps **[Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance)** could help you here.

Basically you can have these models:

```
class BaseModel < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class ThreeFieldModel < BaseModel; end
class TwoFieldModel < BaseModel; end
```

Your migration would contain all fields including a magical `type` column:

```
create_table :base_model do |t|
  t.string :type,   null: false
  t.string :weight
  t.string :height
  t.string :gender
  t.timestamps
end
```

If you decide to use STI, I recommend to read one or two tutorials regarding this topic. Properly using STI with Rails can be difficult at times.